# Script for indicador ema9 of tradingview

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I've been trying to create a script for a few days that will fetch the price of ema9 periods from the tradingview website in the pair btcusdt from binance, can anyone help me? It's not easy for me.

My expectation is that someone will show me a solution to my problem

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.